# Intoducing "remember my name" and "remember my password" options to Pyramid's Authentication

Tags: python, authentication, python-2.7, authorization, pyramid

Following the tutorial,

I have built the authentication system using Auth. APIs of Pyramid.

I would like to learn how to introduce two things (tick boxes) to the login though:

- Remember my name
- Remember my password

How can I achieve this? What do I need to do?

Thank you.

Comment: You should just let the browser do that. The feature you might want to do is "Remember me", meaning the session lasts longer.

Comment: @AntoineLeclair, that is an excellent idea. I have a little question though: can you give me some ideas as to **what** to keep in session cookie to let the user see and perform logged-in actions? Do I encrpyt username+password+ip and keep it, for example? What should I do?

Comment: Do not store password in cookies. Also, you might not want to store user id/name in cookie. I usually only keep a session token (a generated string) on client side (cookie or else), and keep the rest on the server.

Comment: @AntoineLeclair, I read Pyramid source code and I suppose that's the way to go. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

if you are using the cookies based authenticate, then you can also save the user name into the cookies. For password, I am not sure it is a good idea to save it in client side.

I think the better way is to use authenticated_userid to identity the user and return whatever  necessary to the request.